# Can I attain British citizenship abroad by marrying my girlfriend?

Tags: united-kingdom, immigration, uk-citizens, uk-citizenship

My girlfriend is British, but I am an EU citizen. I would love to become British & naturalise and move to the UK with her at some point in my life, but I'm not sure whether this is possible. If I marry her abroad, is there any way to apply for citizenship and become British *abroad*?

Also: I have lived in the Uk for 5 years, but then moved away. Will this count for anything or are these years lost now (with regards to my application)?

Answer (score 1):

Second part: When did you move away? You have the right to permanent residence if you stay for five years (not 4 years and 11 1/2 months), and you lose it if you leave for more than two years. For citizenship, you need to get a certificate that shows you have the right to permanent residence, which you can apply for only if you live in the UK, and you need to have that certificate for more than a year before you can become a UK citizen.